# How to Annotate a boxplot with p values using a combination of ggpubr and ggsignif?

Tags: r, annotations, boxplot, ggpubr

I am trying to create a boxplot that shows multiple comparisons. I made a toy data set that seems to give me the same error as I am getting in my larger one.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsignif)
library(ggpubr)


dat <- data.frame(measurement = c("750","850","900", "300","200","400", "20", "30", "50"),
                   diagnosis = c("Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy","Moderate","Moderate","Moderate",  "Sick", "Sick", "Sick"))

dat$measurement <- as.numeric(dat$measurement)

#List of comparisons
dat.compare <- list(c("Healthy", "Moderate"), 
                    c("Healthy", "Sick"), 
                    c("Moderate", "Sick"))

#Running Anova
dat.lm <- lm(measurement ~ diagnosis, data = dat)
TukeyHSD(aov(dat.lm))
Yields: 
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = dat.lm)

$diagnosis
                       diff       lwr        upr     p adj
Moderate-Healthy -4.3333333 -8.830369  0.1637022 0.0574078
Sick-Healthy     -4.6666667 -9.163702 -0.1696312 0.0433911
Sick-Moderate    -0.3333333 -4.830369  4.1637022 0.9720206

dat.p <- list("0.05","0.04", "0.97")
```

The p adj is what I am trying to annotate to my boxplot with the following code:

```
ggboxplot(dat, x ="diagnosis" , y = "measurement" ,
               color = "diagnosis", palette = "jco",
               add = "jitter") +
  ggsignif::geom_signif(data=dat, 
                        comparisons = dat.compare, annotations=dat.p, 
                        map_signif_level = TRUE)
```

When run the code for the boxplot, it gives me the following error:

```
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_signif()`:
names do not match previous names
```

The end result should look something like this

[image: Boxplot]

As far as I know, the names on the comparison list match the ones in the dataframe. I've been stuck on this for hours, any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that if I change both list formats into vectors, the package will take it without an error.

I appreciate the help @dc37.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to use `geom_signif` to add manually your values on your boxplot.

But you need first to generate a dataframe that will contain the values for p, both x values being compared, and the y position to set your p values.

Here, an example of how you can do it by starting with your Tukey test:

```r
Tukey_data <- TukeyHSD(aov(dat.lm))$diagnosis

library(dplyr)
maxvalues <- dat %>% group_by(diagnosis) %>% summarise(MAX = max(measurement))

pval <- as.data.frame(Tukey_data) %>% rownames_to_column("Group") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Start = unlist(strsplit(Group,"-"))[1],
         End = unlist(strsplit(Group,"-"))[2]) %>%
  left_join(.,maxvalues, by = c("Start" = "diagnosis")) %>%
  left_join(.,maxvalues, by = c("End" = "diagnosis")) %>% ungroup() %>%
  mutate(ypos = c(12,10,8))
  mutate(End = factor(End, levels = c("Healthy","Moderate","Sick"))) %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(ypos = max(MAX.x, MAX.y)*(1+0.25*as.numeric(End)))

# A tibble: 3 x 10
  Group              diff   lwr    upr `p adj` Start    End      MAX.x MAX.y  ypos
  <chr>             <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Moderate-Healthy -4.33  -8.83  0.164  0.0574 Moderate Healthy      5     9    12
2 Sick-Healthy     -4.67  -9.16 -0.170  0.0434 Sick     Healthy      6     9    10
3 Sick-Moderate    -0.333 -4.83  4.16   0.972  Sick     Moderate     6     5     8
```

Then, you can pass it `geom_signif` as follow:

```r
library(ggpubr)
library(ggsignif)

ggboxplot(dat, x ="diagnosis" , y = "measurement" ,
          color = "diagnosis", palette = "jco",
          add = "jitter") +
  geom_signif(data = pval, manual = TRUE,
              aes(xmax = End, xmin = Start, y_position= ypos, annotations = round(`p adj`,3)))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! That would be an interesting "brute force" way of doing it, although if I had to do it for many different plots, it would get a little tricky.

Comment: You're welcome ;) If you had to add it for multiple plots, maybe you can find a way to automatize the generation of the dataset with th y_pos being defined based on a ratio of max y values.